# Display QR Code inside colorbox?

Tags: php, popup, google-api, colorbox, qr-code

I've been able to put some code together and get a QR code to display on my site. Now I'm attempting to get the QR Code to open a larger version inside colorbox. This is the code I've got so far:

```
<a href="<?php echo $????; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" 
class="colorbox" rel="colorbox">
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chld=L&chl=
<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $url; ?>" 
alt="Product QR Code" width="80" height="80" style="float: right" /></a>
```

All the code for colorbox is on this page already as I have products that use this very function. The original code said `echo $popup` but when I use that it shows me the main product image so that's no good. What I can't figure out is what to do with echo in the href section so it calls the image again in the pop-up box but in a larger size?

I've tried using the same url as with the img src but it only returns garbage characters in the pop-up box and doesn't know to turn it into an image instead.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign colorbox, set the photo property to true.  Example:

```
$('a.example').colorbox({photo:true});
```

Colorbox normally uses a regex to determine if a link is pointing to an image or not, but the URL you are using isn't going to pass that regex.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. Let me just say that on the software I'm using, never in a million years would I expect the author to answer such a trivial question. You rock Jack!